# Set all values of ArrayList<Boolean> to false on instantiation

Tags: java, android

Is there an ease way to create an `ArrayList<Boolean>` using Java and have them initially all set to false without looping through and assigning each to false?

Comment: Tried to use SparseBooleanArray? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html

Comment: What do you mean by initially setting all of them to `false`? ArrayList is empty initially when it is created. Your question would have made more sense had you been talking about arrays.

Comment: Well initially I know exactly how many to create, but they may be added to or removed so need to use an arraylist and cant use an array.

Comment: You might also consider `java.util.BitSet`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Do like this

```
List<Boolean> list=new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[10]));
Collections.fill(list, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: `new Boolean(true)` creates unnecessary objects. You should use `Boolean.TRUE` instead.

Comment: `Boolean.TRUE` is unnecessary. Just use `true`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `fill` method from `Collections`:

```
Collections.fill(list, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Another option might be using an array instead of a `List`:

```
boolean[] arr = new boolean[10];
```

This will auto-initialize to `false` since `boolean`'s default value is `false`.

Comment: the boolean[] is a great suggestion and one I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Collections.nCopies`:

```
List<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following

```
Arrays.fill(list, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<Boolean>(size);
list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(size, Boolean.FALSE));
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all we can create a boolean list by
ArrayListlist=new ArrayList(size);
then u can add by if and else conditions whether it is true or not
so
list.add(index position,element);
as element should be of boolean data type u convert from string to boolean
i.e.,
list.add(index position,Boolean.valueOf(element));

Comment: create array list as boolean data type i dont know why it is removed in my answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).